# How can I 'disable' a computed column so that I can apply a migration?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have this migration

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<bool>(
        name: "CancelledVisit",
        table: "Activities",
        type: "bit",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(bool),
        oldType: "bit",
        oldNullable: true);
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<bool>(
        name: "CancelledVisit",
        table: "Activities",
        type: "bit",
        nullable: true,
        oldClrType: typeof(bool),
        oldType: "bit");
}
```

Where `IsComplete` is a computed column, and it uses `CancelledVisit` in its calculation.

When running this migration I get the error

> The column 'IsComplete' is dependent on column 'CancelledVisit'.
> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN CancelledVisit failed because one or more objects access this column.

I thought about removing the record from `sys.computed_columns` and then re-adding it after the migration is done, but I get an error when trying to insert to that table:

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

So I'm wondering what I need to do in order to simply run the above migration, which essentially just makes the `CancelledVisit` column non-nullable

Comment: I think you need to drop the computed column and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my migration to this and it seems to work

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropColumn("IsComplete", "Activities");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<bool>(
        name: "CancelledVisit",
        table: "Activities",
        type: "bit",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: false,
        oldClrType: typeof(bool),
        oldType: "bit",
        oldNullable: true);

    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
        name: "IsComplete",
        table: "Activities",
        computedColumnSql: comp);
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropColumn("IsComplete", "Activities");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<bool>(
        name: "CancelledVisit",
        table: "Activities",
        type: "bit",
        nullable: true,
        oldClrType: typeof(bool),
        oldType: "bit");

    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
        name: "IsComplete",
        table: "Activities",
        computedColumnSql: comp);
}
```

Where `comp` is the SQL string used to generate the computed value